# the connectionstring property has not been initialized

Tags: sql, properties, connection-string

I keep getting the error

> the connectionstring property has not been initialized

I was searching for an hour and i tried to apply solution to my project but, it did not work

I am inserting error log to sql table

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data; 

namespace ErrorLog
{
    internal class LogToDB : ILog
    {
        static string connection_string = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Sever"];

        public void logNow(string strError)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
            List<string> errors = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                string strSQL = "insert_errolog";

                SqlDataAdapter mySA = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn);
                mySA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mySA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@errorMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

                mySA.SelectCommand.Parameters["@errorMsg"].Value = strError;

                DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
                mySA.Fill(myDS);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errors.Add("Error: " + e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();
                conn = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `App.config` file

```
<configuration> 
  <appSettings> 
      <add key="Destination" value="ToSQL"/> 
      <add key="Sever" value="Data Source=MYSQLSEVER ;Initial Catalog=Myproject;User Id=test1;Password=12345"/> 
  </appSettings> 
</configuration>
```

When I inserted data, it was throwing an exception:

> The connectionstring property has not been initialized

Does anyone see the problem in my code ?

Comment: Why are you using `appSettings` instead of the existing `connectionStrings` configuration section?

Comment: Are you sure there should be a space after MYSQLSEVER ?

Comment: Do you really call your server `SEVER` (or did you just miss an `R` in there to make it `SERVER` ??)

Comment: First,  "SEVER" this is right word. Second ,  my using MS SQL 2008

Comment: I am not sure how to use "connectionStrings". can you give me example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection string like this (in app.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyDBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySQLServerDB;   Integrated Security=true" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not opening your connection.

```
conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try harcoding your connection string, to confirm if its working or no

Replace this line with
     static string connection_string = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Sever"];

```
 static string connection_string = "Data Source=MYSQLSEVER ;Initial Catalog=Myproject;User Id=test1;Password=12345";
```

See if that works, if it does, then your connection string value is not fetched from appsettings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Net Developer,

you can convert the code in c#

You should do it like this

make a global connection variable

```
dim con as new SQLConnection
con.connectionsting = "Set your connection string"
con.open

'after when you write what your code then write

con.close
```

it will solve your connection property not initialized problem

hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In this line of code 
 `static string connection_string = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Sever"];`
you should write "`connectionstring`" instead of "`Server`".